# How to write arrays to CSV as columns

Tags: perl, export-to-csv

I have a hash of arrays.  Each hash key is a column name.  Each array is the values for that column.

```
$myHash{column1} = [value1, value2, ..., valueN];
$myHash{column2} = [value1, value2, ..., valueM];
...
```

Each array is of different length.

I want to output this as a CSV file with each array being a column.  I looked at Text::CSV but don't see how to make this structure work with that module.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem description is incomplete. (a) hashes are unsorted. In which order should the columns appear? (or are you keys really named `column1`, `column10` etc.?) (b) what should happen in those cells where `columnX` has less entries than e.g. `N`? Empty values? Output should be truncated to shortest column?

Comment: What would be a meaningful value for the missing values? Also, please don't edit your questions when you already got answers for your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, the problem description is incomplete. My solution assumes:

1. hash keys are named `column1`, ..., `column9`, `column10`, and so on, i.e. the columns in the generated CSV should be numerically sorted by the embedded number.
2. the longest array defines how many rows should be in the generated CSV, i.e. undefined values should map to empty cells.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(max);
use Text::CSV;

# read in hash-of-arrays
my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my($column, @values) = split(' ');
    $hash{$column} = \@values;
}

# column sort order (using Schwartzian transform)
my @column_order =
    map  { $_->[0] }               # [ "columnN", N ] -> "columnN"
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }   # numerical sort, ascending
    map  { [ /^(column(\d+))$/ ] } # "columnN" -> [ "columnN", N ]
    keys %hash;

# calculate highest array index
my $max_index =
    max
    map { $#{ $_ } }
    values %hash;

# transpose hash-of-arrays and print CSV to STDOUT
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
$csv->eol("\n");    
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@column_order);
for my $index (0..$max_index) {
    my @row =
        map { $hash{$_}->[$index] // '' }
        @column_order;
    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@row);
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
column1   1  2  3
column2   4  5  6 7
column3   8  9
column4  10 11 12
column5  13 14 15 16 17 18
column6
column7  19 20 21 22
column8  23
column9  24 25 26
column10 27 28 29 30
```

Run with the embedded test data

```
$ perl dummy.pl
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10
1,4,8,10,13,,19,23,24,27
2,5,9,11,14,,20,,25,28
3,6,,12,15,,21,,26,29
,7,,,16,,22,,,30
,,,,17,,,,,
,,,,18,,,,,
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy using [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) (or Text::CSV, as they share the same API). Just traverse the arrays in your hash by index/row number:

```
my @columns = sort keys %myHash;
my $rows = scalar @{ $myHash{ $columns[0] }};
my $writer = Text::CSV_XS->new();
open my $fh, '>', 'output.csv' or die "Couldn't write file: $!";

# Output headers
$writer->print($fh, \@columns);

# Output payload
for my $row (0..$rows) {
    $writer->print($fh, [map { $myHash{$_}->[$row] } @columns]);
};
```

After the edit of the question, this answer doesn't fully apply anymore. If the arrays are of different length, there is no way to add values for the missing columns.

Comment: Sort::Key::Natural's `natsort` would be better than `sort` If the columns are really named `column1`, `column2`, etc (and quite possibly even if they aren't).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:
1. Covert your hash of arrays into array of arrays
2. Write the csv.

My solution allows you to have blank columns. If you define in your hash columns 1,3,5, columns 2,4 will be blank.

```
my @twoDarray;
foreach my $row (keys %myHash) {
    my ($colIndex) = $row =~ /(\d+)$/;
    $colIndex--;
    $twoDarray[0][$colIndex] = $row;
    foreach my $rowIndex(0..$#{$myHash{$row}}) {
        $twoDarray[++$rowIndex][$colIndex] = $myHash{$row}->[$rowIndex];
    }
}

my $finalFile = "output.csv";
open my $OUT, ">", $finalFile;
my $csvTo = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2, sep_char => ',', allow_whitespace => 1, eol => "\n"});
$csvTo->print ($OUT, $_) for (@twoDarray);
close $OUT;
```